# confidence interval of sum of ARIMA forecast

Tags: r, forecasting

Suppose I have fitted ARIMA model `arima.fit`.

If I want to know forecast the sum of next 12 periods I can use `sum(forecast(arima.fit$mean. h = 12))`

But how can I calculate 95% confidence intervals for this sum?
I think `sum(forecast(arima.fit$upper[,2], h = 12))` and `sum(forecast(arima.fit$lower[,2], h = 12))` wouldn't give me correct intervals

Comment: Answered here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59070/159

Comment: with further explanation here: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-annual-totals/